# Where can I download the source for cron utility?

Tags: c, ubuntu, cron

I have searched for the source for cron, to adapt it to modify/exend it. I can't locate it (thought it would be in coreutils).

Anyone knows where I can get the sources for cron?

BTW, I am running on Linux (Ubuntu 10.0.4).

Comment: this should be moved to superuser

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`apt-get source cron`

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get source cron` should fetch you the sources assuming you have the repositories properly setup.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, I tried to run just that (apt-get source cron), and the tool complains that the archives are not found (404 Not Found). A quick

```
sudo apt-get update
```

will fix the situation and then we could do a

```
apt-get source cron
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU sponsorships mcron (Mellor's cron). Homepage at http://www.gnu.org/software/mcron/. Sources at http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/mcron.git

I don't know if Ubuntu uses this, though.

Comment: It appears that Ubuntu 20.04 LTS uses Vixie Cron, according to the man page.
https://github.com/vixie/cron